# Error 500 when sending form with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am making a website for someone where I need to send a form using AJAX, when I run the site on localhost there is no problem but on the online server I get a `Error 500: Internal server error` when I try to send the form. Does anybody knows the problem? The side is hosted by One.com

The AJAX code:

```
    $("#toevoegenAfb").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "add.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#bestellen").serialize(),
        success: function() {
            alert("Gelukt");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Niet gelukt");
        }
    }
    );
});
```

The only thing I did on the add.php page was this:

```
<?php http_response_code(200);?>
```

To test if it would work, but it didn't.
Anybody who can help me?

Comment: Maybe try without http_response_code ? Maybe your PHP version is lower than 5.4, thus this function is not supported?
Is add.php is located in the same folder with your ajax code?

Comment: Does the server give you any information about what the error is?

Comment: Without makes no difference, and the page were the form is is in the same folder as add.php, the ajaxcode is in a js file in a subfolder.

Comment: The server gives me no information about the error

Comment: It's a server-side error, so it's not the AJAX.  It's probably something wrong with the server-side script.  Try to identify the exact problem by making add.php as simple as possible: `print(hello world);` If that works, add in the rest in pieces to see where the problem happens.

Comment: The solotion was removing the http_response_code, this was the source of the problem.
Thanks Fratyr!

Comment: 500 is a `internal server error` .. means the error in your php code in add.php

Comment: rather check it this way `print_r($_POST);`

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error can stem from the user and group that have access to the files. I'd check there to see what's up. Maybe the answer is as simple as chown-ing.

Comment: It shouldn't on a sane server. Something like that should probably result in a 403, or a 404 if the server doesn't want to disclose anything.

Comment: Actually 500 refers to a configuration error encountered by the server. Therefore, you will need to check your web server log files for the error.